# The SEDE site has an incorrect Stack Overflow icon

Tags: bug, status-norepro, data-explorer, logo

The [Stack Exchange Data Explorer](https://data.stackexchange.com/) (SEDE) has the old Stack Overflow icon.

[image]

[It looks like the unicorn forgot the bar on this site.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=uipTZ2re4Uk)

Comment: Isn't the data for SEDE updated every week or month?! Maybe the icons too?

Comment: Maybe I should of posted this on meta.stackexchange.com ?  Whats the general rule of thumb here, I originally put it here because it was related to SO, but maybe that was wrong of me?

Comment: It is weekly @Rizier123 but only for the data. The usual 6 to 8 applies for other resources...

Comment: You can post bugs on any meta. But @TimStone is more active on MSE so you might get attention quicker there.

Comment: @rene is it possible you / a moderator can move it..I'm not entirely that active on meta sites so I'm not sure how to move it...or even if its worth moving...

Comment: @JonH [Now it's the new logo for me](http://imgur.com/72bdzHu)

Comment: I posted a link in the sede room: http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13526/sede-stack-exchange-data-explorer

Comment: No-repro; the logo is new. It simply links to https://cdn.sstatic.net/stackoverflow/img/apple-touch-icon.png -- same place where the site gets its logo from.

Comment: @NormalHuman - That link shows me the old icon - so what - blame it on the cache?

Comment: You guessed it... Try hard refreshing

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/ dang it

Comment: Even after a hard refresh still the same logo, something must be up with our servers here and our iprism appliance and the cdn.  I've had these issues before with SO's CDN.

Comment: It shows correct for me

Comment: It really must be our iPrism appliance here because even after clearing all of my history, cache, etc I still see the old logo..o well I can live with it.

Comment: I see the new icon next to Compose Query and the old icon in the sites list after a hard refresh. This is a genuine bug.

Comment: The unicorn also forgot the paint.

Comment: looks fixed to me now!

Comment: Yeah its what others have said previous. Your browser has cached the old one.

Comment: @EvanCarslake - Evan no it wasn't that, it was actually fixed.  The icon on the right was fine, it was the main icon on the left that I pointed to in my screen shot that was incorrect.  So caching actually wasn't to blame!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Now it appears to be fixed.  I just went to the site and at first it appeared with the old image, after a hard refresh the new image came up.  Case can now be closed!  Thanks stack devs!

Comment: http://shouldiblamecaching.com/